# SVG Background image not working in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg, background-image

I'm using the following to get an SVG icon display as a background image:

```
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="9" height="14" viewBox="0 0 9 14">
    <path d="M8.398 5.75q0 0.102-0.078 0.18l-3.641 3.641q-0.078 0.078-0.18 0.078t-0.18-0.078l-3.641-3.641q-0.078-0.078-0.078-0.18t0.078-0.18l0.391-0.391q0.078-0.078 0.18-0.078t0.18 0.078l3.070 3.070 3.070-3.070q0.078-0.078 0.18-0.078t0.18 0.078l0.391 0.391q0.078 0.078 0.078 0.18z" style="fill: #582dc6"></path>
    </svg>');
```

This works fine in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox.

Could someone let me know why it's not working in Firefox?

Thank you.

Comment: as a side note the icon is simple for such complex SVG, it can be simplified